# Why can I use a constant initialization as if-condition?

Tags: swift, if-statement, initialization, conditional-statements

While reading the official Apple Guide I found this

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello \(name)"
}
```

There is a constant declaration and assignment where I — as a beginner — expected an expression returning a `boolean`. But the condition of this `if` statement seems to get `true` as the value, because the code inside the parentheses is being executed.

Does the initialization of a constant return a `boolean` value or something that a `if` statement can use as a condition?

Answer (score 0):

This is called Optional Binding. Quoting from the Basics -> [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) -> Optional Binding section of the Swift Language Guide.

> You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary constant
>   or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while statements
>   to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value
>   into a constant or variable, as part of a single action.

What this `if let` construct is doing is checking if `someOptional` is exists. If it isn't `nil`/`.None` then it "binds" the Optional value to a constant.

```
if let constantName = someOptional {
    ...
}
```

This can be thought of as:

```
if someOptional != nil {
    let constantName = someOptional!
    ....
 }
```